# Запрос в 2 таблицы с одинаковыми именами столбцов

Tags: mysql, mysqli, массивы, php, запрос

У меня есть 2 таблицы с одинаковыми именами столбцов, которые связаны по ID.
Когда я делаю подобный запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM tb1, tb2 WHERE tb1.id = tb2.id
```

В массиве у меня есть все, но там, где совпадают имена, нет ассоциативного ключа...
Например:

```
array(
 [0] => "Title form tb1",
 [title] => "Title form tb1",
 [1] => "Title form tb2"
)
```

Это, конечно, обосновано и логично. Но как можно это обойти, не добавляя псевдонимы к каждому столбцу отдельно? Возможно ли приставить префикс или еще как-то справиться, не разделяя на 2 отдельных запроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте присвоение имён as . В вашем случае будет примерно:

```
select title.tb1 as title1, title.tb2 as title2 from tb1 left join tb2 on (tb1.id = tb2.id)
```

На выходе получите массив формата:

array(
'title1'=>'title.tb1',
'title2'=>'title.tb2'
)

Comment: Я же написал:

"Но как можно это обойти, не добавляя псевдонимы к каждому столбцу отдельно?"

У меня в базе около 15 столбцов с одинаковыми именами. И мне как-то не резон каждый так перебирать. Если есть способ массово добавить к столбцам из одной таблицы префикс или суффикс, то было бы здорово

Comment: Алиасы для того и созданы чтобы такие ситуации как у Вас разруливать. Присваивать можно за один раз или одному имени поля, или имени одной таблицы.
ЗЫ. Писал как то запросы к 12 таблицам для выборки информации по автомобилю из базы текдока. Выбиралось больше 100 столбцов, из них было много повторяющихся имён, каждый ручками прописывал. Не бойтесь ручной работы, она повышает скил .

Comment: В этом случае мне проще сделать 2 запроса. Потому что, как вы понимаете, большое количество кода делает его нечитабельным. А так, отмечу ответ правильным. Спасибо за потраченное время и помощь)

Answer (score 1):

У Вас же php под рукой, автоматизируйте генерацию запроса с алиасами...

```
<?php

$fields = array();
foreach(array('title') as $field) {
  $fields[] = 't1.'.$field;
  $fields[] = 't2.'.$field.' t2_'.$field;
}
$fields = implode(',', $fields);
$sql = "SELECT $fields FROM t1, t2 ...";
```

Answer (score 0):

почитайте про [LEFT JOIN](http://dimonchik.com/sql-left-join.html)

Comment: Не то. Опять же, проблема, я так полагаю, не в MySQL, а в механизме обработки запросов в PHP. И ее я хочу как-то обойти.